# Use package shadowing symbols

Tags: package, lisp, common-lisp

For instance I have this package definition which shadows COMMON-LISP:LISTEN :

```
(defpackage :shadows
  (:use :common-lisp)
  (:shadow #:listen)
  (:export #:listen))
```

And then I want to use this package from another package, say

```
(defpackage :light
  (:use :common-lisp
        :shadows))
```

What is the purpose of shadow if I cannot actually override Common Lisp symbols when using the package ?

Comment: What you probably want to do is construct a package which is 'like' `CL` but where some symbols are different.  You might want to look at [conduits](https://github.com/Inaimathi/conduits), which lets you do this.  (Disclaimer: I wrote this, and am ashamed to say that I don't have a world-visible copy of it at present: this is someone else's).

Answer (score 3):

## Simple

The `:shadow` argument to [`defpackage`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpkg.htm)
affects the definition of the package `shadows`,
not the later use of `shadows` in `light`.

You need to use [`shadowing-import`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_shdw_i.htm):

```
(defpackage #:shadows
  (:use #:common-lisp)
  (:shadow #:listen)
  (:export #:listen))
(defpackage #:light
  (:shadowing-import-from #:shadows #:listen)
  (:use #:common-lisp #:shadows))
(eq 'light::listen 'shadows:listen)
==> T
(describe 'light::listen)
==>
SHADOWS:LISTEN is the symbol SHADOWS:LISTEN, lies in #<PACKAGE SHADOWS>,
is accessible in 2 packages LIGHT, SHADOWS.

 #<PACKAGE SHADOWS> is the package named SHADOWS.
 It imports the external symbols of 1 package COMMON-LISP and
 exports 1 symbol to 1 package LIGHT.
```

## Bulk

If you need to do bulk shadowing, you would need to use individual functions
([`make-package`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mk_pkg.htm),
 [`import`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_import.htm),
 [`export`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_export.htm),
 [`shadow`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_shadow.htm),
 [`use-package`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_use_pk.htm)):

```
(defparameter *my-shadow-list* '(#:car #:cdr))
(make-package '#:my-package :use nil)
(import *my-shadow-list* '#:my-package)
(export *my-shadow-list* '#:my-package)
(shadow *my-shadow-list* '#:my-package)
(use-package '#:cl '#:my-package)
(make-package '#:my-user)
(shadowing-import *my-shadow-list* '#:my-user)
(use-package '(#:cl #:my-package) '#:my-user)
(describe 'my-user::car)
==>
MY-PACKAGE:CAR is the symbol MY-PACKAGE:CAR, lies in #<PACKAGE MY-PACKAGE>,
is accessible in 2 packages MY-PACKAGE, MY-USER.

 #<PACKAGE MY-PACKAGE> is the package named MY-PACKAGE.
 It imports the external symbols of 1 package COMMON-LISP and
 exports 2 symbols to 1 package MY-USER.
```

You might find [`macroexpand-1`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mexp_.htm) useful in decising how get where you need to go:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(defpackage #:light
                 (:shadowing-import-from #:shadows #:listen)
                 (:use #:common-lisp #:shadows)))
==>
(EVAL-WHEN (:COMPILE-TOPLEVEL :LOAD-TOPLEVEL :EXECUTE)
 (SYSTEM::%IN-PACKAGE "LIGHT" :NICKNAMES 'NIL :USE 'NIL :CASE-SENSITIVE NIL
  :CASE-INVERTED NIL)
 (SYSTEM::SHADOWING-IMPORT-CERROR "LISTEN" "SHADOWS" NIL "LIGHT")
 (USE-PACKAGE '("COMMON-LISP" "SHADOWS") "LIGHT") (FIND-PACKAGE "LIGHT")) ;
T
```

PS. Shadowing ANSI CL standard names is not a very good idea for your code readability.

Comment: Well I have tens of these symbols so every time I want to use this lots-of-shadows package I have to explicitly :shadowing-import-from, which kinda sucks, really. I know it's not your fault, thanks.

Comment: If `DEFPACKAGE` would just stack the used packages symbols in order and not raise conflict errors, it would be perfectly fine for me.

Comment: You can use `shadowing-import` for bulk shadowing or travel 50 years back in time and convince Lisp designers that your idea of "stacking used packages symbols in order" is a good idea. Note that you will have to explain how to do shadowing-import of `s1` from `p1` and `s2` from `p2` when all symbols are in all packages ;-)

Comment: Can't I just shadow `defpackage` ? =D

Comment: Yes, you can also `shadow` `shadow`.

Comment: @thodg `UIOP:DEFINE-PACKAGE` has `:MIX` for that.

Answer (score 3):

OK so there actually is a handy way to do this.

In my many-shadows package I export a `shadowing-import-from` function. It looks like this :

```
(defun shadowing-import-from ()
  `(:shadowing-import-from :many-shadows
     ,@(package-shadowing-symbols :many-shadows)))
```

And then, in the light defpackage I just READ-EVAL it :

```
(defpackage :light
  (:use :common-lisp
        :many-shadows)
  #.(many-shadows:shadowing-import-from))
```

So it is explicit that something was shadowed and that I want to use the symbols from many-shadows in priority. And it is short enough to be documented and used pragmatically.

Thank you @sds for pointing me to `:shadowing-import-from`.

Answer (score 2):

> *What is the purpose of shadow if I cannot actually override Common Lisp symbols when using the package?*

The purpose of a package having a list of shadowing symbols is to resolve conflicts arising from package use by that package. Shadowing has no effect on anything exported.

When a package uses others, conflicts can arise when two or more used packages export a symbol by the same name. Similarly, conflicts can also arise between a used package and symbols in the local package. These conflicts are treated as errors. On a symbol-by-symbol basis, shadowing squelches these conflicts. A symbol, which is present in the package, is added to its list of shadowing symbols. Any conflict is then silently resolved in favor of that symbol.

Being a shadowing symbol doesn't bestow any special powers on a symbol when it is regarded from outside the package where it has that status.

For each package, we have to separately arrange the "visibility stack", including its own shadowing symbols, if necessary.