# Package Shadowing for Multiple Packages and Symbols - how to use cl21

Tags: package, common-lisp, shadowing

Loading the Quicklisp system :cl21 (Common Lisp for the 21st Century) produces many conflicts with the :cl package. (But this is by design.) Is there a convenient way to specify that any conflicts should be resolved in favor of :cl21? The following definition resolves conflicts individually, but is tedious, since there are hundreds of symbols needing shadowing:

```
(defpackage :my-pkg
  (:use :cl :cl21)
  (:shadowing-import-from :cl21.core.hash-table :hash-table-count)
  (:shadowing-import-from :cl21.core.sequence :position :substitute-if)
  (:shadowing-import-from :cl21.core.package :rename-package :use-package)
  (:shadowing-import-from :closer-mop :standard-generic-function)
  ...)
```

The solution I have so far is to write a macro called `defpackage*` that expands into a `defpackage` like that above:

```
(defun package-externals (pkg-name)
  "Returns the external symbols in a named package."
  (let (pkg-syms)
    (do-external-symbols (sym (find-package pkg-name) pkg-syms)
      (push (list pkg-name sym) pkg-syms))))

(defmacro defpackage* (pkg-name use-list shadow-pkg-names)
  "Adds shadowing imports from a list of package names."
  (let ((shadow-externals (loop for pkg in shadow-pkg-names
                            append (package-externals pkg))))
    `(defpackage ,pkg-name ,use-list
       ,@(loop for ext in shadow-externals
            collect `(:shadowing-import-from ,@ext)))))
```

The third argument `shadow-pkg-names` is the list of package names from which the exported symbols will be extracted. For example, a macro call might look like:

```
(defpackage* :my-pkg
  (:use :cl :cl21)
  (:cl21.core.hash-table :cl21.core.sequence :cl21.core.package ...))
```

However, I'm not sure how to get the complete list of packages to insert in the macro from a Quicklisp system like :cl21. (A manual count of the :cl21 packages comes in at 30, with varying numbers of exported symbols from each package.)

At a more general level, is this the simplest way to resolve conflicts *en masse*? Note that there is another post at [Use package shadowing symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44596132/use-package-shadowing-symbols) which deals with a similar issue, but I'm finding it hard to follow (except perhaps for the idea of using a reader macro to splice in the long list of :shadowing-import-from clauses). Also note that loading :cl21 does not seem straightforward, as I've had to start from scratch every time with (but don't know why):

```
(let ((quicklisp-init (merge-pathnames "quicklisp\\setup.lisp" (user-homedir-pathname))))
  (when (probe-file quicklisp-init)
    (load quicklisp-init)))

(ql-dist:install-dist "http://dists.cl21.org/cl21.txt")

(ql:quickload :cl21)
```

Comment: I think `CL21` is meant to be `:USE`d instead of `CL` rather than together with it.

Comment: Use only cl21 like this: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/cl21.html#install-and-use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't `use` both `cl` and `cl21`.  Just use `cl21` if you want that.

`Cl21` both exports symbols for functionality it changed with respect to `cl` and re-exports any unchanged symbols.  It is designed as something like a replacement “base” package.

Comment: But then it looks like you have to just "know" which :cl functions have been modified by :cl21 (maybe a hundred?). For example, `mapcar` is unmodified requiring `cl:mapcar`, however `make-hash-table` is modified so just use `make-hash-table`. I'd still like to know how to collect the packages internal to a Quicklisp system like :cl21.

Comment: @davypough: Use `map` instead of `mapcar`, see https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/cl21.html#mapping.  These are conscious decisions.  `Cl21` is meant to be a new language derived from `cl`.  It is not a pure extension.  Personally, I see it  more as an opinionated thought experiment, but _chaqun son goût_.